# How to make a template appears on admin console

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

After installing openshift, I can visit admin console and use image streams on the home page to new app.

My question is ... I have imported some templates and can use them with oc, but failed to see these new imported templates on the home page of admin console, what should I do to make these templates displayed on the home page?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using OpenShift 3.7, you now need to go under the *Select from Project* menu item of *Add to Project* to see templates that were added to a user project. Only those added to the global `openshift` project appear under *Browse Catalog*.

[image]

Comment: hi Graham, that works, many thanks. BTW, could you explain what is " global openshift project"?

Comment: Like you create your own project to work in, there is a pre-created project called ``openshift``. This is special in that any image streams and templates created in it are accessible to all users of the cluster. It is where everything you see in browse catalog, which isn't your own, comes from.

Comment: If this refers to "openshift" project, I did create template in this project, but failed to see the template created by myselft in home page, but I can see it under "select from project", then select openshift project, so, how to make my template appears in home page?

Comment: In OpenShift 3.7 there now exists what is called a template service broker. It is possible that in order for it to display templates under _Browse Catalog_, that they need to be annotated in a certain why. I don't know the details right now so you will need to check the documentation.